# Copy combobox value to excel cell

Tags: c#

I have one combobox (comboBox1) that has 6 names and I need to copy selected value to excel cell. For that I have one form that creates an excel file when I click on a button (button1). Value must go to where I have "name" on code. How can I do that? Thank you.

Windows Form click button:

```
    xlWorkSheet.get_Range("U58", "X58").Merge(false);
    xlWorkSheet.get_Range("U58", "X58").Borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop].Weight = 2d;
    xlWorkSheet.get_Range("U58", "X58").Borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].Weight = 1d;
    xlWorkSheet.get_Range("U58", "X58").Borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight].Weight = 2d;
    chartRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("U58", "X58");
    chartRange.FormulaR1C1 = "name";
    chartRange.HorizontalAlignment = 3;
    chartRange.VerticalAlignment = 2;
    chartRange.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
    chartRange.Font.Name = "Arial";
    chartRange.Font.Size = 8;
    chartRange.Font.Bold = false;
```

Comment: Welcome, and a bit of advice: please, next time don't include so many unneeded details. It looks like ***all*** of the Excel stuff is unneeded for this question. Instead you could (should) have focused on simply saying that you have a ComboBox and need to get the selected text from it. Easier for you to create as a question, and a lot easier for us to comprehend and answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking about *SelectedItem* of ComboBox. If all ComboBox items are strings then try this :

```
if(comboBox1.SelectedItem != null){
    string name = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(); 
....
}
```

Comment: chartRange.FormulaR1C1 = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(); Thank you Gokhan!